# Modify user-agent WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, http-headers

In my windows phone 8 app, I call to external **APIs** developed by client may be in PHP.
They told us that the user agent is showing **NativeHost**.
They want it to be **Windows Phone** so that they could better track the windows phone requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting [the `HttpWebRequest.UserAgent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Tr this one

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "my-user-agent-name");
```

Hope you are using HTTP client to make call to external API

Comment: No we use webreqeust.            var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(URL)) as HttpWebRequest;


            request.Headers["user-agent"] = CNT.Resources.AppResources.ConfigUserAgentHeader + ";";
            request.Headers["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = CNT.Resources.AppResources.ConfigUserAgentHeader + ";";
            if (APIHelper.APIHandshake != null)